# Job driver and 3rd party jars

Tags: hadoop

I'm able to run M/R jobs where the mapper and reducer required to use 3rd party jars. I'm registering those jars in -libjars while invoking the hadoop jar command. I'm facing a strange problem, though, when the job driver itself ( extends Configured implements Tool ) required to run such code ( for example notify some remote service upon start and end). Is there a way to configure classpath when submitting jobs using hadoop jar? Seems like -libjars doesn't work for this case...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/me/context/DefaultContext
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at com.me.bigdata.mr.pnm.PnmDataCruncher.run(PnmDataCruncher.java:50)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
        at com.me.mr.pnm.PnmMR.main(PnmDataCruncher.java:261)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.me.context.DefaultContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

I was trying using export HADOOP_CLASSPATH_USER_FIRST=true and -Dmapreduce.task.classpath.user.precedence=true, but still I'm getting errors.

I'm running hadoop 1.0.4.

Comment: How do you instantiate the Configuration object? Make sure to retrieve it in your driver class via `getConf()`

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=jar1:jar2    hadoop jar your_jar  your_class ...........
```

make it all in one line of shell command